# Remove padding and margin in PreferenceCategory title

Tags: android, xml, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to remove the default padding and margin set in the title of a PreferenceCategory like this :

[image: problem_image]

```
<PreferenceScreen 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:background="?attr/backgroundColor"
        android:title="@string/settings_category_title_generals"
        app:iconSpaceReserved="false">

        <ListPreference
            android:id="@+id/chooseLanguage"
            android:defaultValue="@string/settings_language_default"
            android:dialogTitle="@string/settings_language_dialog_title"
            android:entries="@array/settings_language_entries"
            android:entryValues="@array/settings_language_values"
            android:key="pref_language"
            android:summary="@string/settings_language_summary"
            android:title="@string/settings_language"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_language" />

    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

but it seems that in the attributes there is nothing about this. I also searched on the internet, but I didn't find anything useful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share your layout file pls?

Comment: @Roon13 sorry, done !